# TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Tags: angular

I am trying to display sum in my angular 4 application. I have implemented the following code but it is giving me the error

structure

```
export interface NpvResults  {

            captiveInsYear: number[];
            captiveInsPremiumPaid: number[];
            captiveInsTaxDeduction: number[];
            captiveInsLoanToParent: number[];
            captiveInsCapitalContribution: number[];
            captiveDividentDistribution: number[];
            captiveInsTerminalValue: number[];

        }
```

The array is initialized to the following value

```
this.sourceResults.captiveInsPremiumPaid = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

```
{{NpvResults?.captiveInsPremiumPaid.reduce(sum) | number:'.0-3'}}
```

and then in the component

```
public sum = (total, currentValue) => total + currentValue;
```

Comment: What does your input look like? There isn't enough information to help you.

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Can you show the definition of `captiveInsPremiumPaid`?

Comment: In `sourceResults` you implement the interface `NpvResults`, make sure you are initializing the array here, this should resolve the `no initial value` problem

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `this.sourceResults`?

Comment: Acutally my issue has been resolved. One of my elements werent intialised.